# prevent multiline textbox stretching when text is added

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Below is my `HTML`:

```
<table width="100%" >
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="tbNewNote" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" CssClass="width:100% "/>
    </td>                                
  </tr>
</table>
```

When the `textbox` is filled with text, it widens beyond the edge of the screen.

**How can i get rid of such behavior?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code, removed CssClass="width:100%", you provide class here not css property. Secondly I added a fixed width to your TextBox, now it will not expand.

```
 <table width="100%" >
      <tr>
       <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbNewNote" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Width="200px"/>
       </td>                                
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: FYI: The better answer to this question is below, which was answered by Shubham. To prevent any resizing of the multi line text box, add to the style of the text box the following: "resize:none;"

Answer (score 13):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="20" style="resize:none;" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you add text to the textbox programmatically until the next postback.

Comment: @shiggity can you please explain it further by which I will try to help in any other way if possible......

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Let me try to Explain: In asp TexMode Multiline is the alternative of "TextArea" in Html, Rows 5 minutes the height will be up to 5 lines and after that scroll bar will come, Column 20 minutes in one line it will accept 20 characters and after that it will become a new line and finally the style:"resize:none" is to disable manual resizing of the Input field both Vertically and Horizontally, Hope it helps.

Comment: @shiggity you can create a script and call it from the code, btw why you need to call it from code? Any specific reason for that?

Comment: @Shubham uhh like any time you need to set the text dynamically, when it's being retrieved from a database, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Make the following class in your css and use it in textbox whose width you want to fix:

```
.CSSclass{

resize:none;
}
```

if you want same for all textbox with textmode multiline you can write following in your css:

```
.textarea{
resize:none;
}
```

Comment: This should have been the official answer, but it still does not solve it for Firefox or Chrome. There is still a bottom right-hand corner "grabber" and you're able to stretch the box out. How to avoid this?